# Getting error Timeout performing GET using StackExchange.Redis in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis

I have created one demo and used with StackExchange.Redis for caching some values using Asp.net mvc with c#. But I can't connect redis cache in my local system.
This is my redis cache class with connection string:

```
 public class RedisCache{
 private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => { return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("abv,password=63sd,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,allowAdmin=true"); });

    private static ConnectionMultiplexer _connection
    {
        get { return _lazyConnection.Value; }
    }
}

 public T Get<T>(string key, RedisDatabase database)
    {
        var result = default(T);
        var value = _connection.GetDatabase((int)database).StringGet(key);
        if (!value.IsNull)
        {
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When I am run my code then I am getting below like error:

```
Timeout performing GET UserSearch, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never,             queue: 2, qu: 0, qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0,
 clientName: Abc-PC, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/abv, keyHashSlot: 322, IOCP:
 (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:     (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=4,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for    some common client-side 
 issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

any one know how can fixed this error so can you please let me know.

Comment: Did you read the http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts link that it suggested?

Comment: @mjwills do you have any idea about this issue how can I resolve? I have checked link by given you but can't understand what is issue is there.